# I am trying to create a header that displays hashtags on top a string and then hashtags on the bottom, it keeps saying header_message not defined

Tags: python, string

```
def create_header(size:str)->list:
    header_message = ['Harry Potter Typing Trainer']
    return header

def display_header(header:str)->None:
    display_str = ''
    for index in range(len(header)):
        display_str = f'{display_str}{header[index]}'
      # print(display_str)
    print('#' * len(display_str))
    print(display_str)
    print('#' * len(display_str))
```

def main()->None:
header = create_header(header_message)
display_header(header)

main()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. You defined `header_message` inside a function that's [local variable scope](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp) this mean that header_message is not visible outside create_header function. To modify global variable inside function you could use [global keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp#main/h2-3) but it not good practice
2. In `create_header()` you return `header` variable which is not defined here (remember local scope) it should look like this at least

```
def create_header(size:str)->list:
    header_message = ['Harry Potter Typing Trainer']
    return header_message
```

Or short version

```
def create_header(size:str)->list:
    return ['Harry Potter Typing Trainer']
```

3. `header = create_header(header_message)` here passing `header_message` is not needed at all. It can be changed to

```
header = create_header("This string is not needed either because function does not use it")
```

At this point program runs:

```
def create_header(size:str)->list:
    header_message = ['Harry Potter Typing Trainer']
    return header_message

def display_header(header:str)->None:
    display_str = ''
    for index in range(len(header)):
        display_str = f'{display_str}{header[index]}'
      # print(display_str)
    print('#' * len(display_str))
    print(display_str)
    print('#' * len(display_str))


def main()->None:
    header = create_header("This string is not needed either")
    display_header(header)

main()
```

With output

```
###########################
Harry Potter Typing Trainer
###########################
[Finished in 35ms]
```

4. But code still could be improved by removing unnecessary function parameter create_header(**size:str**). Also [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) like `:str` and `->list` are not needed and usually not used. Python does not enforce types aka would not throw an error if types were wrong it would only show warning. Maybe it useful in some circumstances but it makes more clutter than use. So after all we get:

```
def create_header():
    header_message = ['Harry Potter Typing Trainer']
    return header_message

def display_header(header):
    display_str = ''
    for index in range(len(header)):
        display_str = f'{display_str}{header[index]}'
      # print(display_str)
    print('#' * len(display_str))
    print(display_str)
    print('#' * len(display_str))


def main():
    header = create_header()
    display_header(header)

main()
```